# Load Example.xml build script to jenkins

Tags: asp.net, xml, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying out CI for first time and have chosen Jenkins after reading good reviews about it.

I have installed the Jenkins for Microsoft. Now i have a .NET web applications BuildScript which is `Example.xml`, which consist of ant scripts. My question is how can I load this file to Jenkins so that it builds my application as the script does in command prompt?

Comment: Basically i need to build a ANT script using Jenkins.

Comment: i finally figured out the solution by reading Jenkins documentation

Comment: Then can you add an answer that explains the solution, and accept it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a new project, click on configure, there is section named BUILd under that you get a option like invoke Ant select that and you get a textbox to enter the target to be executed inside Ant file.
Then click on Advanced option below, there you can enter the following

```
Build file : Path to your build file(example.xml)
Properties : label=$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER 
Java Options : -Dbranch=trunk -Dversion=HEAD
```

this would do the job.